# item response theory - criteria for selecting items

Tags: r, item-response-theory, scale-construction

I'm trying to use IRT to select the best items for a one-factor scale that has 20 items.
I was wondering what I need to be looking at if I wanted to select 5 or so items from these items (for a short version of the scale). 
I would really appreciate any suggestions/references!

Answer (score 1):

Higher slope values are better - this are discrimination parameters, the higher the slope, the greater the ability of the item to distinguish ability.

A range of difficulty parameters - or difficulty parameters in the area where you want the measure to have the most precision.

Comment: thanks! I'm wondering whether there are some criteria; Also, can the slopes be too high? some of my items have slopes going up to 6.5 and I'm not sure if it's always the higher the better...

Comment: Ah, yes, slopes can be too high. This is often caused by two items that are highly related (essentially the same item repeated twice) and is caused by a local dependency.